# Error : (#1) An error occured while creating the share on php sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a php/javascript API on my website for posting messages on the user wall depending on actions on my website.
I use on one side the javascript API for logging the user to the App and the PHP sdk on the other side for posting on the user wall some link.

The thing is that when I launch the PHP graph API method, Facebook respond me with the given error :
`error :
    array(1) {
    'error' =>
    array(3) {
    'message' =>
    string(46) "(#1) An error occured while creating the share"
    'type' =>
    string(14) "OAuthException"
    'code' => int(1)
    }
    }`

The php call is like this :

`$facebook->api( '/me/feed/', 'post' ,$data );`

And the data with the $data array are just the message and the link

But if I do the exact same code in javascript( using the FB.api('/me/feed' ) method), the message is well posted on my wall.

Is there something I have missed ?

Comment: Hello, have you managed to solve this, as I am getting the same error.

Comment: Not at all sorry. But reason is the server configuration, I have tried on my personnal server with no restriction and everything was fine...

Comment: Its likely to do with the attributes you're trying to `POST` in `$data`.